# why my list only shows one result (python)

Tags: python, list, loops

I just code a program which count red pixels in each photos in the folder:

```
def sum_pixel(img):
    sum = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]
    return sum

def red_part(Min_L, Max_L,img):
    redP_sum = 0
    x = Min_L
    while x < Max_L+1:
        redP_sum = redP_sum + np.where(img == x)[0].shape[0]
        x+=1
    red_percentage = redP_sum/sum_pixel(img)*100
    return [redP_sum, red_percentage]

def read_directory1(directory_name):
    # this loop is for read each image in this foder,directory_name is the foder name with images.
    for filename in os.listdir(r"./"+directory_name):

        #img is used to store the image data 
        img = cv2.imread(directory_name + "/" + filename)
        array_of_img.append(img)

        img_L = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        result = []
        redP = red_part(60,100,img_L)
        result.append(redP)


        return result
```

there have 3 photos in the folder, but only shows one result
`[[223247, 7.535916339233875]]`

If I use print, there shows 3 result, this is correct because the folder contains 3 images.

```py
def read_directory2(directory_name):
    for filename in os.listdir(r"./"+directory_name):
        #img is used to store the image data 
        img = cv2.imread(directory_name + "/" + filename)
        array_of_img.append(img)

        img_L = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        result = []
        redP = red_part(60,100,img_L)
        result.append(redP)

        print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[223247, 7.535916339233875]]
[[43506, 2.932113742236025]]
[[77523, 5.224710468426501]]
```

so how can I use list to show the correct result?

Comment: You do `result = []` inside the for loop. So every time the loop iterates and processes an image, the previous contents of `result` are lost.

Comment: In addition to moving `result = []` to above the `for`, you should move `return result` to after the loop, by removing 4 leading spaces in front of the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `read_directory1(directory_name)`, you are resetting the value of the `result` variable to `[]` in every iteration. You are also calling `return` inside the loop, it will cause the function to exit in the first item of the loop. See the comments in the code below:

```py
def read_directory1(directory_name):
    # this loop is for read each image in this foder,directory_name is the foder name with images.
    for filename in os.listdir(r"./"+directory_name):

        #img is used to store the image data 
        img = cv2.imread(directory_name + "/" + filename)
        array_of_img.append(img)

        img_L = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        result = [] # <- Resetting the value for every file. This needs to be moved out of the loop
        redP = red_part(60,100,img_L)
        result.append(redP)


        return result # <- currently returning in the first iteration of the for loop, it should also be moved out of the loop
```

This should fix the function:

```py
def read_directory1(directory_name):
    # this loop is for read each image in this foder,directory_name is the foder name with images.

    # define the result variable outside of the loop
    result = []
    for filename in os.listdir(r"./"+directory_name):

        #img is used to store the image data 
        img = cv2.imread(directory_name + "/" + filename)
        array_of_img.append(img)

        img_L = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        redP = red_part(60,100,img_L)
        result.append(redP)

    # return result after all the items have been processed in the loop
    return result
```